# JQuery perform events based on Toggle

Tags: jquery, html

I am using new jQuery and playing around with it using HTML.

I am trying for `If else` events based on button click.

If a user clicks a button I am creating a checkbox and appending a button below.

And if the user clicks a button again I am removing the checkbox below the button and if he clicks again I append...

How do I implement this?

What I tried on button click:

```
$(document).on("click", "#button", function () {
    CreateCheckBox();
    $("#Test").toggle("hidden");
}
```

But it will not work as it will create a checkbox every time. What is best way to do this in jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an working example in Jsfiddle for you to look at. I hope it helps you out.

http://jsfiddle.net/rnhjX/14/

```
$("#my-button").click(function() {
   if ( $('#checkbox-toggle').children().length > 0 ) {
        $('div#checkbox-toggle').empty();
   }else{
       $('div#checkbox-toggle').append('<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-name"> hello')
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).on('click', 'button', function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('create')) {
        $('<div><input type="checkbox"><button>Delete</button></div>').appendTo('body');
        // for jsfiddle test purposes I am creating the checkbox using jQuery and a button to delete
        $(this).toggle(); // hides append button
    } else {
        $(this).parent().remove(); // removes the checkbox and delete button
        $('.create').toggle(); //shows append button
    }
});
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/NAkLW/1/**

Answer (score 0):

Just Change Your Code as below :

```
$(document).on("click", "#button", function () {

    $("#CheckboxID").toggle();
});
```

You are forget to close " ) " as well as you  have passed  wrong argument in toggle() function.

Answer (score -1):

```
$("button").on('click',function(){
    $('#checkbox').toggle();
    if($('#checkbox').css("display") != "none"){
        $('#checkbox').hide();
    }
    else
    {
        $('#checkbox').show();
    }
});
```

it's not exactly what you're looking for, but it's a good alternative..